# Best way to move an unexpected column in a Pandas DF to a new DF?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Wondering what the best way to tackle this issue is. If I have a DF with the following columns

```
df1()
type_of_fruit   name_of_fruit    price
.....           .....            .....
```

and a list called

```
expected_cols = ['name_of_fruit','price']
```

whats the best way to automate the check of df1 against the expected_cols list? I was trying something like

```
df_cols=df1.columns.values.tolist()
if df_cols != expected_cols:
```

And then try to drop to another df any columns not in expected_cols, but this doesn't seem like a great idea to me. Is there a way to save the "dropped" columns?

```
df2 = df1.drop(columns=expected_cols)
```

But then this seems problematic depending on column ordering, and also in cases where the columns could have either more values than expected, or less values than expected. In cases where there are less values than expected (ie the df1 only contains the column name_of_fruit) I'm planning on using

```
df1.reindex(columns=expected_cols)
```

But a bit iffy on how to do this programatically, and then how to handle the issue where there are more columns than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set difference`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/) using `-`:

Assuming `df1` having cols:

```
In [542]: df1_cols = df1.columns # ['type_of_fruit', 'name_of_fruit', 'price']
In [539]: expected_cols = ['name_of_fruit','price']

In [541]: unwanted_cols = list(set(d1_cols) - set(expected_cols))

In [542]: df2 = df1[unwanted_cols]
In [543]: df1.drop(unwanted_cols, 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: perfect thank you! Will need to add some logic to help with a case of an expected_col is missing, but can figure it out from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` along the columns axis to split the DataFrame succinctly. In this case, check whether the columns are in your list to form the grouper, and you can store the results in a dict where the `True` key gets the DataFrame with the subset of columns in the list and the `False` key has the subset of columns not in the list.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3]],
                  columns=['type_of_fruit', 'name_of_fruit', 'price'])
expected_cols = ['name_of_fruit','price']
```

#### Code

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.columns.isin(expected_cols), axis=1)))

# If you need to ensure columns are always there then do
#d[True] = d[True].reindex(expected_cols)

d[True]
#   name_of_fruit  price
#0              2      3

d[False]
#   type_of_fruit
#0              1
```